# Can't connect to an api endpoint in my express server

Tags: javascript, express

I am new to express and currently having issues connecting to an api

below is my code

```
const express = require("express");
const session = require("express-session");
const MongoStore = require("connect-mongo");
const flash = require("connect-flash");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const axios = require("axios");

const app = express();
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();
let sessionOptions = session({
  secret: "Javascript is so cool",
  store: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: process.env.CONNECTIONSTRING }),
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: { maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, httpOnly: true },
});

app.use(sessionOptions);
app.use(flash());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.set("views", "views");
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
const router = require("./router");
const apiRouter = require("./apiRouter");

const options = {
  url: "https://rms.pythonanywhere.com/api",
  method: "",
  json: {},
};

app.use("/", router);
app.use(options.url, apiRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

Below is the file i created for routes that goes to the api

```
const express = require("express");
const apiRouter = express.Router();
const request = require("request");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const userController = require("./controllers/userController");
const pageController = require("./controllers/pageController");

apiRouter.post("/user/create", async function (req, res) {
  const api_url = "https://rms.pythonanywhere.com/api";
  const fetch_res = await fetch(api_url, options);
  const json = await fetch_res.json();
  res.json(json);
});

module.exports = apiRouter;
```

When i submit my registration form i want it to send it post request to the url of the api and recieve its response. But whenever i send a post request to the api url it returns an error of (can't send post request to /user/create)

What i really want to achieve is to connect to this api link (rms.pythonanywhere.com/api) and be able to direct my routes for registration and login with some other routes to the api. I've been battling with this for over a week now. Please guys help me out, I'm new to express
Thanks in advance guys

Comment: Point of clarity: "it returns an error of" means "this is the response body returned by the API"?

Comment: No, it isn't. that error is not a response from my api.

Comment: Then what is raising that error? And what response is the API returning, or is the request actually not being sent in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I think your express app is unable to find the **apiRouter** so, you need to use express router first with the help of **express.use()** method.

You can add below line to your code.

`express.use("/", apiRouter);`

Comment: i have done that too, still did'nt solve my issues

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your response. Although none was actually the solution, but it gave me a clue of what i needed to do.

What i used in solving my issues was `axios`. i `required("axios")` after installing from npm store and den i used it in my `apiRouter.post("/user/create")` route. Below is what i did to solve the issue

```
apiRouter.post("/register", async function (req, res) {
  const api_url = "https://rms.pythonanywhere.com/api";
  axios.post(api_url + "/user/create/", {
      first_name: req.body.first_name,
      last_name: req.body.last_name,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password,
      user_type: req.body.user_type,
      username: req.body.username,
}). then((response) =>{}).catch((error){})

});
```

I was able to send the data's from my post request made in `apiRouter.post(/register)` and recieved the success response in my `then()` and error response in my `catch()` block.